# Objects are not persisted by Doctrine

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

last couple of days I've been busy making a form using Doctrine and MongoDB. Companies should be able to reserve tables, chairs, .. at a certain event by use of this form. The snippet below shows the controller for this form.

The 'ObjectMap' object maps the amount of a certain object to the object itself. The controller creates all the 'ObjectMap' objects, and adds them to the company object. However, the 'ObjectMap' objects are persisted by Doctrine (they show up in the database) but the company object isn't modified at all, there is no database request made by MongoDB. The persist() function seems to have no effect at all.

```
public function logisticsAction(Company $company)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new LogisticsForm($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()), $company);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get('_company_logistics_edit');
            $objects = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                ->getRepository('Jobfair\AppBundle\Document\Company\Logistics\Object')
                ->findAll();

            foreach($objects as $object) {
                $requirement = $formData['objectRequirement_'.$object->getId()];

                $map = new ObjectMap($requirement, $object);
                $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($map);

                $company->addObjectMap($map);
                //print_r($company->getObjectMaps());
            }
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($company);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
                'success',
                'The information was successfully updated!'
            );

            return $this->redirect(
                $this->generateUrl(
                    '_company_settings_logistics',
                    array(
                        'company' => $company->getId(),
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

The Company object is defined here:

```
class Company{
/**
 * @ODM\Id
 */
private $id;

/*
 * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Jobfair\AppBundle\Document\Company\Logistics\ObjectMap", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $objectMaps;

public function __construct($name = null, $description = null)
{
    $this->objectMaps = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getObjectMaps()
{
    return $this->objectMaps;
}

public function getObjectsArray()
{
    $objects = array();
    foreach($this->objectMaps as $map)
        $objects[] = array(
            'name' => $map->getObject()->getName(),
            'amount' => $map->getRequirement()
            );
    return $objects;
}

public function addObjectMap(ObjectMapDocument $objectMap)
{
    $this->objectMaps[] = $objectMap;
}

public function removeObject(ObjectMapDocument $objectMap)
{
    $this->objectMaps->removeElement($objectMap);
}
```

}

Comment: I don't use mongo but from your description is sounds like your setCompany is never being called.  Quite a common issue.  Many developers are surprised that Doctrine does not call this automatically when defining a relation.  Of course it could be something completely different.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Why would I need a setCompany method? The addObjectMap function gets called, I have already checked this, so the company object looks fine up to the point where it should be persisted to the database, but then things go wrong.